# Python highlight each word if text contains combination of words

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with combination of words highlighting.

Current code finds matches in text and wraps words with  tag.

```
import re

text = 'Just for testing, it is fantastic. Lets do it. Cmon'
keywords = ['testing', 'is fantastic']


def highlight(text, keywords):
    replacement = lambda match: "<mark>" + match.group() + "</mark>"
    text = re.sub("|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)), replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    print(text)

highlight(text, keywords)
```

**Output**: `Just for <mark>testing</mark>, it <mark>is fantastic</mark>. Lets do it. Cmon`

**Problem**: if `is fantastic` combination of words are found I want to wrap each word in this combination.

**Expectation**: `Just for <mark>testing</mark>, it <mark>is</mark> <mark>fantastic</mark>. Lets do it. Cmon`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your replacement function, you can do other regex:

```
import re

text = 'Just for testing, it is fantastic. Lets do it. Cmon'
keywords = ['testing', 'is fantastic']


def highlight(text, keywords):
    replacement = lambda match: re.sub(r'([^\s]+)', r'<mark>\1</mark>', match.group())
    text = re.sub("|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)), replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    print(text)

highlight(text, keywords)
```

Prints:

```
Just for <mark>testing</mark>, it <mark>is</mark> <mark>fantastic</mark>. Lets do it. Cmon
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
keywords = ['testing', 'is fantastic']
```

with:

```
keywords = ['testing', 'is', 'fantastic']
```

and it will work.

Comment: Maybe for op solution is enough, but what if op wants to mark `is fantastic` but not `is terrible`

Comment: I like this answer. You can also have the caller `chain(*[re.split(r"\s+", x) for x in keywords])` to do this programmatically without changing the behavior of the function, which seems like it works as you'd expect already. Making the function responsible for pre-processing the argument in unusual ways seems like a poor design choice and makes the function less reusable. Better to simply call the function with the correct data.